# suggestion for video lectures on algebraic topology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, online-resources

can anyone suggest me any good video lecture series for algebraic topology other than N.J.Wildberger videos. If it is equivalent to Munkres topology (algebraic topology section) it should be great.
thanks for your suggestion

Comment: A tag of reference might help clarify the question.

Comment: does anyone have any suggestion for me.I am anxiously waiting for it

Comment: You may try to read the book "Algebraic Topology,A primer" by Satya Deo.It is a beautiful book to learn the subject

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a bit late:-), but if you still interested in this topic 
I would definitely recommend this video course:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxFGokyYo6g&list=PLpRLWqLFLVTCL15U6N3o35g4uhMSBVA2b